# FTPSClient hangs on storeFile - file sent arrives with zero bytes

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm using `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient` for sending files to another server. But the program hangs after

```
boolean stored = client.storeFile(fileName, is);
```

The file is sent but on the server it has zero bytes.

I tried sending the same file to the same server using `Filezilla` and it gets transferred with no problems, so I don't think this is a firewall issue.

I also made sure that my `InputStream` is reading the file by printing its contents.

Here's my code:

```
FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient();
InputStream is = null;

client.connect(AppValues.ftpurl);
client.login(AppValues.ftpname, AppValues.ftppass);
is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\path\\filename");
boolean stored = client.storeFile(fileName, is);
System.out.println("Stored? " + stored);
```

The Stored printout is never called, and the file arrives with zero bytes.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FTPClient client = = new FTPClient();
InputStream is = null;
client.connect(AppValues.ftpurl);
client.login(AppValues.ftpname, AppValues.ftppass);
client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); 
client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\path\\filename");
boolean stored = client.storeFile(fileName, is);
System.out.println("Stored? " + stored);
```

Comment: I'm using version 3.3.

Comment: new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\path\\filename");

is your path is correct?

Comment: Like I said in the post I made sure the file is being read. So yes.

Comment: I use Ftp not FTPS and get desired o/p.
use this two and try!!!

ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

Comment: Actually could you please update your answer to include the information in the comment that solved my problem? The info in the answer as it currently stands is not the solution.